# Config is not defined - почему переменная недоступна из вне

Tags: node.js

Имеется  такой код:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/data/config.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var config = JSON.parse(data);
});

console.log(config);
```

Почему пишет ошибку

> config is not defined

Файл перекрёстно читается, как можно расширить действие переменной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы создали переменную внутри анонимной функции, поэтому она недоступна снаружи этой функции. Чтобы решить эту проблему, следует написать так:

```
var config;

fs.readFile(__dirname+'/data/config.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    config = JSON.parse(data);
});

console.log(config);
```

Но этот код не будет работать так, как вы ожидаете. Функция `readFile` *асинхронная*, поэтому на момент выполнения `console.log` значение переменной `config` будет ещё не получено и вы увидите в консоли "undefined".

Для, того, чтобы этого избежать, пишите асинхронный код:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/data/config.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var config = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(config);
});
```

Или наоборот, синхронный:

```
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/data/config.json', 'utf8'));

console.log(config);
```

Синхронный код блокирует поток выполнения, поэтому лучше им не злоупотреблять, но асинхронный код сложнее писать. Выбор за вами.

Comment: Замечу, что конкретно для чтения конфига _в начале выполнения программы_ нет ничего плохого в синхронном чтении файла. Всё равно без него ничего работать не будет.

Comment: И ещё, конкретно тут проще использовать `config = require('./data/config.json')`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, абсолютно согласен по обоим пунктам.